# Where is task stack allocated in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

We all know methods such as **Task.Run** or **Parallel.ForEach.**
Each one of them creates tasks which runs according to options in separate thread or in thread from thread pool. But, where is their stack residing? In some generation heap or there is special place for them?

For example, I can create 1000 tasks, and where is their stacks residing? Will their physical address move at some point if I call GC.Collect()?

Comment: This is quite specific in respect to a particular CLR implementation, the underlying OS, and even the CPU architecture. For example, Windows has specific support for allocating (and growing) thread stacks, in-line with how x86/x64 memory management works.

Comment: Indeed. There are very few requirements in the C# language that any stacks exist at all (really just Stack allocation - there are only 44 occurrences of `stack` in the C# language spec and half of those are example classes called `Stack`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stack is a purely unmanaged implementation detail.  The processor needs a stack to get anything done, it cannot meaningfully execute any code without it.  It is strongly tied to a thread, another purely unmanaged detail on normal CLR hosts.

It is located in memory where the OS kernel decided to allocate it when it created the thread, it is random.  Intentionally random to give malware a hard time, the stack is an attractive way to turn data into malicious code.  Not just the location is random, also the exact offset inside the stack segment where the stack starts is random.

It never moves after it is created, the GC does not tinker with it.  It does need to know about it, object roots can be stored on the stack.  Reliable stack walks are thus a hard .NET requirement, also the basic reason that the CLR can always produce a good stack trace when a program dies on an unhandled exception.  Running out of stack space is a serious problem, the processor cannot continue to execute code.  Serious enough to name a programmer's web site after that problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Tasks that are based on delegates executed by a `TaskScheduler` run on whatever stack the `TaskScheduler` uses. The default scheduler uses thread pool threads. These are (mostly) normal .NET threads.

In particular, `Task.Run` creates such a default scheduler based task.

Tasks based on `TaskCompletionSource` do not execute code and do not need a stack. They are completed based on some external condition such as an IO completing or a timer ticking.

.NET has no built-in support for heap-based stacks or "green threads". You will generally not find such a thing in real code.